# ГАР ФИАС в PostgreSql

Tags: java, postgresql

стоит задача подключить ИС к ГАР ФИАС, я скачал их XML(29ГБ на сегодняшний день) начал разбираться что как связанно, и обнаружил такую проблему : в таблице **AS_ADM_HIERARCHY.XML** есть поля **REGIONCODE, CITYCODE, PLACECODE** и т.д. , в кодорыъ указанны коды принадлежности, например *PLACECODE="25"* Вопрос: где взять таблицу соответсвий кодов и названий(Городов, Регионов и т.д) в 29 Гб не нашел. Может кто знает ? буду премного благодарен.

Comment: https://wiki.gis-lab.info/w/%D0%A4%D0%98%D0%90%D0%A1

Comment: Ну например посмотреть внимательнее. Стоит начать с верхнего уровня Регион, у него взять код(objectid), от него получить список входящих в него муниципальных районов, выбрать нужный и тд. Там вполне логичное деление на уровни. Таблица as_addr_obj (она идет до земельного участка включительно, а потом номера домов и тд по моему в другой таблице уже)

Comment: [Регион, у него взять код, он него получить список входящих в него муниципальных районов] как это сделать-вот в чем вопрос, где хранятся регионы и грода

Comment: К примеру,указан CITYCODE=9, где и как найти город под номером 9?

Comment: @framzik я Вам выше таблицу назвал as_addr_obj. Читайте ответ полностью. Пример sql кода для получения всех регионов (SELECT * FROM as_addr_obj WHERE level = 1). Там будет и Ваш object id

Comment: @wigravy спасибо,разобрался

Comment: @wigravy, сейчас в упомянутом файле XML содержатся строки вида: OBJECT ID="1596" OBJECTID="1515" OBJECTGUID="5d236ae9-9f00-471a-91ef-fe2112df186b" CHANGEID="3932" NAME="Ходзь" TYPENAME="аул" LEVEL="6" OPERTYPEID="1" PREVID="0" NEXTID="0" UPDATEDATE="2015-11-02" STARTDATE="1900-01-01" ENDDATE="2079-06-06" ISACTUAL="1" ISACTIVE="1". Как в таких записях выбрать действующие TYPENAME всех LEVEL и построить их деревья вложенности?

Comment: @AlexeyLot создайте запрос на SO, с учетом правил форума. Если у Вас есть БД, а не просто перебор xml файлов, то берите верхний уровень Региона и от него стройте дерево ниже. Регион -> Муниципальный округ -> Поселение\Город\Населенный пункт и тд.